# How send 2 List from C# controller to view with ViewBag

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am sending months (get the value from File path) and File path to the MVC view so I can show a List of the month that is linked to the File to download it like this:

```
 OCT(that is linked to file path)
 Nov (that is linked to file path)
 December (that is linked to file path)
```

This is my Controller C# code:

```
     public ActionResult Help()
    {

        var releaseNoteFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/ReleaseNotes"));

        List<string> month = new List<string>();
        foreach (var releaseNoteFile in releaseNoteFiles)
        {
            month.Add(new Regex("([^A-Z]*)([a-zA-Z]*)").Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(releaseNoteFile).Split('.').Last()).Groups[2].Value);
        }
        ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth = month;   /Has October,Nov,...
        ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles = releaseNoteFiles; /Has Path to the File

        return View();
    }
```

This is my view that I have a problem with how to send 2 lists (Filename and Path) This code shows the list 2 times.

```
          @foreach (var item in ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth)
                    {foreach (var item2 in ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles)
                        {
                            @item <a href="@item2">@item</a>
                            <br />
                        }
                      }
```

Comment: You are just iterating over all of your `releaseNoteFiles` for each month (by `@foreach (var item in ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth)`, so if you have 12 months you will see all of your `releaseNoteFiles` 12 times on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to print the month and the monthfile with hyperlink on the view, see the below code if that sorts you out.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.releaseNoteFilesmonth)
{
    var matchedmonthfile = (ViewBag.releaseNoteFiles as string[]).Where(x => x.Contains(item)).FirstOrDefault();
    @item <a href="@matchedmonthfile">@matchedmonthfile</a>
    <br />
}
```

Comment: getting this error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: I have updated the code and removed lambda expression as an argument error, pl. check now.

Comment: Error as this: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'  in line 2 - var matchedmonthfile - @Vaibhav J

Comment: I have checked the code it is working fine, pls make sure you cast releaseNoteFiles as string[] as i mentioned in the code